# Int argument passed from C to Assembly loses its sign

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, abi

I am trying to implement a sign function in assembly (64 bit) and then calling it from C.
My function takes in one argument: an unsigned int and returns an int, which can be -1 (if the argument is negative), 0 (if the argument is 0), and 1 (if the argument is positive).

My program works well for detecting positive numbers and zero but if I pass a negative number as the argument then it handles it as a positive one and returns 1.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int sign(signed int);

int main()
{
    signed int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("num: %d sign: %d\n",num,sign(num));
    return 0;
}
```

sign.asm:

```
global sign

section .text
sign:
    test rdi,rdi
    js neg_lab
    je zero_lab

    mov rax,1
    jmp end_lab

neg_lab:
    mov rax,-1
    jmp end_lab
    
zero_lab:
    xor rax,rax

end_lab:
    ret
```

At first I thought that the problem was in the assembly code, so I set the tested register's value to a positive number then a negative number and then finally zero. It worked well.  It recognized negative numbers too.
After that, I now think the problem is with the passing of arguments. I think the sign of the arguments is getting lost somewhere, or that the C way of storing negative numbers is just not compatible with assembly?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `unsigned int` is 32 bit not 64. Also why does your function take `unsigned`...

Comment: Oh I see. It's a typo.  First I started without writing signed/unsigned before the args. It didn't work. Then I taught I will write signed before everything even it's signed on default that may fix that but it didn't.

Comment: `test rdi,rdi` -> `test edi,edi`. You can put `unsigned` there, and it won't break your code, but it's just unnecessary.

Comment: Replacing rdi wit edi did fix my problem. So I have to use 32 bit part of the register. Thank you.

Comment: Unlike some ISAs where the calling convention requires the caller to sign-extend all args to the full register width, x86-64 calling conventions only guarantee the contents of the actual arg's type width.  Garbage is allowed above that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have declared your function to take a 32 bit integer but implemented it to work on 64 bit integers.  So when you pass, say `-1`, to the function, it actually receives `0x00000000ffffffff` instead of `0xffffffffffffffff` as you might expect.

There are two ways to fix this:

Either, rewrite the declaration to use 64 bit integers:

```
extern long long sign(unsigned long long);
```

or rewrite the code to use 32 bit integers, e.g. like this:

```
global sign

section .text
sign:
    test edi,edi
    js neg_lab
    je zero_lab

    mov eax,1
    jmp end_lab

neg_lab:
    mov eax,-1
    jmp end_lab
    
zero_lab:
    xor eax,eax

end_lab:
    ret
```

Note that return value and argument can have their sizes decided independently.  They don't have to have the same size.